# How do I get filename and line count per file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script to count lines per file in a given directory:

```
dir -Include *.csv -Recurse | foreach{get-content $_ | measure-object -line}
```

This is giving me the following output:

```
Lines    Words    Characters    Property
-----    -----    ----------    --------
   27
   90
   11
   95
  449
  ...
```

The counts-per-file is fine (I don't require words, characters, or property), but I don't know what filename the count is for.

The ideal output would be something like:

```
Filename        Lines
--------        -----
Filename1.txt      27
Filename1.txt      90
Filename1.txt      11
Filename1.txt      95
Filename1.txt     449
  ...
```

How do I add the filename to the output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
dir -Include *.csv -Recurse | 
   % { $_ | select name, @{n="lines";e={
       get-content $_ | 
         measure-object -line |
             select -expa lines }
                                       } 
     } | ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer another solution :

```
Get-ChildItem $testPath | % {
    $_ | Select-Object -Property 'Name', @{
        label = 'Lines'; expression = {
            ($_ | Get-Content).Length 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I operate on the. TXT file, the return value is like this ↓

```
Name  Lines
----  ----
1.txt    1
2.txt    2
3.txt    3
4.txt    4
5.txt    5
6.txt    6
7.txt    7
8.txt    8
9.txt    9
```

The reason why I want to sort like this is that I am rewriting a UNIX shell command (from *The Pragmatic Programmer: Your Journey to Mastery* on page 145).

The purpose of this command is to find out the five files with the largest number of lines.

At present, my progress is the above content,i'm close to success.

However, this command is far more complicated than the UNIX shell command!

I believe there should be a simpler way, I'm trying to find it.

```
find . -type f | xargs wc -l | sort -n | tail -5
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following script that gives me lines in files of all sub directories in folder c:\temp\A. The output is in lines1.txt file. I have applied a filer to choose only file types of ".TXT".

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\A -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | % {
    $_ | Select-Object -Property 'Name', @{
        label = 'Lines'; expression = {
            ($_ | Get-Content).Length 
        } 
    } 
} | out-file C:\temp\lines1.txt
```